# Catching fish in a pond

Tags: probability

> Suppose the amount of fish in a pond follows a Poisson distribution. A fisherman catches each fish (independently) with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. If $N$ is the  total number of fish he catches, what is $\mathbb{P}(N=n)?$ Suppose now that he  has caught $N=M$ fish, what is $\mathbb{P}(K=k)$ where $K$ is the number of fish  he has not caught?

Say there are $x$ fish in the pond. $\mathbb{P}(N=n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$

$$\mathbb{P}(K=k\,|\,N=M)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(K=k\cap N=M)}{\mathbb{P}(N=M)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}( N=x-k)}{\mathbb{P}(N=M)}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x-k-M}$$

This must be wrong because I haven't taken into account the Poisson distribution. How can I incorporate $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\lambda^x\frac{1}{x!}e^{-\lambda}$ into this ($X$ is the number of fish in the pond)? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the pun "fish following a Poisson distribution" intentional? (Poisson means fish in french).

Comment: @dkuper you know I would always frame Poisson distribution question in term of fishes, there is definitely nothng fishy about this, completely normal.

Comment: can you please give us what you attempted? as it stands, i am stuck on proving Rieman's conjecture, because I have never tried it, is that the situation you are in? if so, please have a go at the question yourself.

Comment: @Lost1 Do you think you could give me a hint? I am having a lot of trouble with this question...

Comment: yes, i actually know the answer to this question, but i have not had time to write it. do you know about moment generating functions?

Comment: @Lost1 Unfortunately I don't - this question comes from a beginners course in probability, we haven't covered generating functions yet. Is there another way? Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: Yes, there is a pedantic way. The answer should be Poisson distributed with half of the original parameter.

Comment: by the way, please consider accepting the answer someone else provided to your other question if you are satisfied. you can do so by pressing tick and you can use the up and down arrow to indicate if you find the answer is helpful or not.

Comment: i have written a hint, i will upload it now.

Comment: @Lost1 Thanks for your time

Comment: needed ipad to charge, posting now.

Comment: have you managed to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

See this answer. Have fun with this...

Comment: Thanks for this. Just one thing: why does the second probability not allow for $k<n?$ (the probability that he misses more fish than he has caught)

Comment: @simon if you have 3 fishes in the pond, can you catch 5 fishes? if you catches 3 fishes, can there only be two fishes in the pond in total?

Comment: i basically left out all the algebra, which I did do myself, but I think you should do it yourself. you need expand out the binomial coefficients and see lots of factorial cancels.